# Re-index Webcontent with solr as search

Tags: solr, liferay, liferay-6

I want to reindex only webcontent part in liferay and hence I am using ReIndex functionality provided under `Control panel---> App` Manager for Web content only.

However, we are using Solr for search indexing. When I reindex webcontent from Control panel, the button gets disable and in logs I get "Load index from cluster is not enabled" message and nothing else in logs.

Is there any way to reindex only Webcontent when Solr is used instead of lucense?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can reindex webcontent using Index Checker portlet.

Download it from: https://web.liferay.com/es/marketplace/-/mp/application/70121999

Select only "webcontent" and check "output synced object", click "Check index" and then "Reindex".